# axis.text.y - fixed width possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have two graphs in a row, both should have the same width since I want to share one legend. The data of the y axis are different, though and since one is quite high, the other quite low, the width is different:

[image]

Is there a possibility to set something like this:

`axis.text.y = theme_text( width = 10 )`

or so? Any other suggestions? Any resources I might have missed?

Thanks a lot in advance! And pre-XMAS greetings from Germany :)

Till

Comment: It would be much easier to help you, if you would provide us with some example code

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/users/188568/tielefeld your account?

Comment: yes, it's here: https://gist.github.com/1514919 . Sorry for the verbosity!

Comment: An easy fix may be to simply divide the y values in the lower plot by 10000 and change the axis label to indicate this: _measures (x10000)_ or something.

Answer (score 0):

A few (similar) suggestions:

- @joran pointed out in a comment, you could just divide the lower plot by 10000
- Or convert to percentages (if appropriate)
- Use logs (if appropriate).

Option 1 is probably the best and easiest.